# Mac: Screen shot selection implementation? (ability to select part of screen)

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, screenshot

I am trying to implement something like Macs Selection screen shot where I am able to to select part of the screen by dragging the cursor, and get the resulting coordinates (CGRect).

So something like this:

[image: Something like this]

I have been looking at AVScreenShack which sounds like it is supposed to do this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html

But it does not seem to be working for me. I end up getting something that looks like:

[image: THis]

And when I try to set the coordinates it does not do anything.

I see that this is the relevant code, I believe:

```
- (IBAction)setDisplayAndCropRect:(id)sender
{  
for (NSScreen* screen in [NSScreen screens]) 
  {
      NSLog(@"SCREEN %@", screen);
    NSRect frame = [screen frame];
    NSWindow * window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [window setAlphaValue:.5];
    [window setLevel:kShadyWindowLevel];
    [window setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];
    DrawMouseBoxView* drawMouseBoxView = [[DrawMouseBoxView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    drawMouseBoxView.delegate = self;
    [window setContentView:drawMouseBoxView];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

[[NSCursor crosshairCursor] push];
}
```

So maybe it is doing something other than what I want (to be able to select the area on the current view).

Has anybody done something like this? I am thinking there has to be something out there doing something similar.

Thanks

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet, or are you still searching for a solution?

Comment: @ThomasJohannesmeyer Yup, it's solved. It's part of this project here: https://github.com/Jonovono/Cutter. (It actually makes it so you can take a video of a selection of the screen, not a screenshot.)

Comment: Does your solution work with more than 2 monitors? Because even the Apple sample does not.

Comment: I have not tried with more than 1 monitor! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I’ve tried it with 3 and it didn’t work. ;-)

Comment: THanks for the heads up! That was not something I had planned for hah. I'll take a look at it when I go back to that project :)

Comment: Same happened to me. I only used 2 monitors for the development of one of my applications. My code was stable for 2 screens, but crashed on more than 2. It get's quite tricky if one Retina screen is in the chain, too. I'm working on a solution and may link it here, when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you.

[ScreenSnapshot](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ScreenSnapshot/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code that shows how to do this. check  it

Comment: This seems to only take a full screen snapshot. I'll look into it a bit more, but I had found this one earlier and I couldn't see where it let me define the screen area.